Graphics & Sound Problems: `nomodeset` & the `snd_hda_intel` driver
Thinkpad W541 (Haswell + Nvidia) fails to boot, freezing at:
Job gpu-manager.service/ start running...
With nomodeset it freezes at:
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver
With nomodeset and removing gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode, it boots:
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
   Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core processor Integrated Graphics driver: N/A
   Device-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] driver: N/A
   Display: X11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0 driver: X:
      loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev, modesetting dri: swrast gpu: N/A
      resolution: 1920x1080
   API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1  renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)

$ lsmod | egrep '^i915|^nouveau'
i915          4145152   0
nouveau       2838528   0


I'd be grateful for any input.
Edit: snd_hda_intel is a sound driver, which apparently comes in three forms, legacy, sst, and sof.  Someone reverted to legacy on Fedora using the option snd-intel-dspcfg.  I tried snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=X for X=1, 2, 3; but none allowed me to boot.  It seems that is related to a legacy option, snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=X for X=0, 1 (1=default).  Setting that to 0 did not help.
